# How to expand a newcommand where it is called?

Tags: macros, collect, expandafter

I need to gather things that will be presented at the end of the document, as shown bellow

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{somethings}

\newcommand{\collectthing}[1]{
    There is a #1 here!
    \begin{collect}{somethings}{}{}{}{} 
        \noindent #1 collected in section \arabic{section}
    \end{collect}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

\collectthing{ThingA}

\section{Section B}

\collectthing{ThingB}

\section*{Things collected}

\includecollection{somethings}

\end{document}
```

However, since the command `\collectthing` is expanded only when I call the command `\includecollection`, all sections are shown with the same value they share when they are expanded, as it can see in the result bellow

[image]

How do I fix it, so it shows the proper section number at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're storing `\arabic{section}`, not the current value.

Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{somethings}

\newcommand{\collectthing}[1]{%
  There is a #1 here!%
  \expandandcollect{somethings}{\noindent #1 collected in section~\arabic{section}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\expandandcollect}{mm}
 {
  \text_expand:n { \begin{collect}{#1}{}{}#2\end{collect} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

\collectthing{ThingA}

\section{Section B}

\collectthing{ThingB}

\section*{Things collected}

\includecollection{somethings}

\end{document}
```

Beware that this is not safe with fragile commands, so you'll need `\protect` in front of them. The created file will contain

```
\noindent ThingA collected in section~1

\noindent ThingB collected in section~2
```

[image]

Without `expl3`, but not as satisfying:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\expandandcollect}[2]{%
  \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\begin{collect}{#1}{}{}#2\noexpand\end{collect}%
  }\x
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks! A simple and clear solution!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a little `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse} % In case you are using LaTeX version older than 2021
\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{somethings}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\collectthing}[1]{
    There ~ is ~ a ~ #1 ~ here!
    \exp_args:Nx \bmello_collectthing_internal:nn { \arabic{section} } { #1 }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \bmello_collectthing_internal:nn
  {
    \begin{collect}{somethings}{}{}{}{}
        \noindent #2 ~ collected ~ in ~ section ~ #1
    \end{collect}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

\collectthing{ThingA}

\section{Section B}

\collectthing{ThingB}

\section*{Things collected}

\includecollection{somethings}

\end{document}
```

An internal command `\bmello_collectthing_internal:nn` is defined, and by using the `x`-type argument (`\exp_args:Nx` changes `\bmello_collectthing_internal:nn` to `\bmello_collectthing_internal:xn`), `\arabic{section}` is expanded before passing to this command.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish the tokens forming `#1` to be expanded, you can do something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{somethings}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}

\newcommand{\collectthing}[1]{%
  There is a #1 here!
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
    \number\arabic{section}%
  }{%
    \begin{collect}{somethings}{}{}{}{}%
    \noindent #1 collected in section~%
  }%
  \end{collect}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

\collectthing{ThingA}

\section{Section B}

\collectthing{ThingB}

\section*{Things collected}

\includecollection{somethings}

\end{document}
```

[image]